# How can I vectorize approximate matrix multiplication using sum of outer products?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

Assume I have two matrices, `A` and `B`, and I want to compute `C = AB` using the sum of outer products.
I have written this function to achieve that, but I am wondering If can eliminate the for loop and vectorize it,

```
import numpy as np

def mul_opx(A, B, pd):
    # Approx. matrix multiplication using outer product
    n, m = A.shape
    p = B.shape[1]
    C = np.zeros((n,p), dtype=A.dtype)
    dum = np.zeros_like(C)
    for t in range(m):
        dum = np.outer(A[:,t],B[t,:]) / pd[t]
        C = C + dum
    C = C / m
    return C

d = 1000
A = np.arange(d**2).reshape((d,d))
B = np.arange(d**2).reshape((d,d))

# Full Matrix Multiplication
C = A @ B

# Approximate Matrix Multiplication
# choosing half random vectors/rows from A/B
k = np.random.choice(d, int(d/2))
Ap = A[:,k]
Bp = B[k,:]

# Unifrom probability vector
pd_uniform = np.full(d,1/d)

# Approximate product
C_hat = mul_opx(Ap,Bp, pd_uniform[k])
```

This type of product is useful when matrix dimensions are very large say 10^6 x 10^6

Comment: `A @ B` works fine.

Comment: The trick of having fast Python code is that you don't write it. You use libraries instead which are hopefully not written in Python. So consider trying `A @ B` as suggested already, and if it fails you, a next thing to check some Swiss-army knife, like [`einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html)

Comment: Yes but I am actually trying to compute an approximation and will not use all of the outer products in calculating my result.

Comment: @AtifAli - Please include a [mre] of your actual problem in your question. Sampling rows and columns to approximate can be done with `numpy` but sounds like a really bad approach.

Comment: sorry for this question here what is the name of this operation `@`

Comment: You are using `matmul/@` in the loop.  Just from reading code it isn't obvious how this is any different from using it on the whole arrays, `A@B`. `dot/matmul/einsum` are the 'vectorized' sum-of-products functions.

Comment: @RabeeQasem, `@` is the operator for `np.matmul`.  That's an extension of `np.dot`.

Comment: For this small example, your function is 10x slower than the `A@B`.  So `A@B` is the "vectorization".  For your question to be meaningful, the function needs to return something different, something that is worth doing in a slower manner.

Comment: Let's say I have matrices with an order of 10^6 x 10^6 then with approximate computations, I can reduce the number of computations to less than half. How do we choose which outer products to add is another topic.
Then I feel my method will be faster as I have to do half of the multiplication than a full matrix product of this scale.

Comment: To compute your "approximation" (it is not an approximation) vectorized: `Ap @ Bp`.

Comment: I agree `Ap @ Bp` seems to be the best way here

Comment: To vectorize your new requirements: `Ap/(len(k)*pd_uniform[k]) @ Bp`. Still not an approximation.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny This is the best answer and it speeds up the code by 20 times. I wish I could accept this as an answer.

Comment: You probable want to put replace=False in your random.choice call.

Comment: No, this is intentional. it can be done both ways. with replace=False the results will be better but it would cause an extra computation load. @Learningisamess

Comment: Okay, I was not sure of your intention there, seems like you want a 'bootstrap' kind of resampling. Noted.

Answer (score 6):

As others have mentioned this could be a good use case for [einsum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html).
Writing your operation in that *language* can be done with

```py
np.einsum( 'ij,ik->jk',A,B)
```

Repeated `i` index for the sum, and unrepeated `j` `k` for the outer product. A quick benchmark seems to show a 2x speedup compared to @Tomer's proposed answer. This will depend on the input size of course and I leave to you to see how it generalizes to linear sizes in the 10^6 range, the memory footprint should also be better with the einsum.

[image]

Comment: I have updated the question with the exact code. And I need to divide each of the outer products by a number. How would I do that?

Answer (score 4):

You can try using `np.multiply.outer(A,B)`.

Assume you have the following data:

```
a = np.array([[4, 2],
              [2, 2]])

b = np.array([[4, 3],
              [4, 0]])
```

You want to do the following two multiplications:

```
np.outer(a[:,0],b[0,:]) = array([[16, 12],
                                 [ 8,  6]])
np.outer(a[:,1],b[1,:]) = array([[8, 0],
                                 [8, 0]])
```

This can be done using the `mp.multiply.outer` method. The `np.multiply.outer` "Apply the ufunc op to all pairs (a, b) with a in A and b in B." ([See description here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html#numpy.ufunc.outer)). This function perform all possible outer products between `A` and `B`, which in this simple example results in a `(2,2,2,2)` shape matrix. Obviously, you do not need all possible outer product, you just need to extract the one you want from this matrix.
You can see that:

```
np.multiply.outer(a,b)[0,:,0,:] = array([[16, 12],
                                         [ 8,  6]])
np.multiply.outer(a,b)[1,:,1,:] = array([[8, 0],
                                         [8, 0]])
```

Using this method you do not need to do the for loop, but you execute redundant computations. However, the `numpy` package is optimized, and perhaps this will be faster (for very large `A` and `B` you can try speeding things up using the jit decorator

Another method in which you do not compute redundant computations is via using `np.newaxis` to expand the matrices before multiplication.

Using the same `a`, `b` from above, perform the following:

```
a[:,:,np.newaxis] = array([[[4],
                            [2]],

                           [[2],
                            [2]]])
b[:,np.newaxis,:] = array([[[4, 3]],

                           [[4, 0]]])
```

Now you can simply do multiplication to receive:

```
a[:,:,np.newaxis]*b[:,np.newaxis,:] = array([[[16, 12],
                                              [ 8,  6]],

                                             [[ 8,  0],
                                              [ 8,  0]]])
```

This is the exact result of the outer products without the redundant computation of `np.multiply.outer`. All that is left is to sum over the 1st dimension as follows:

```
results = np.sum(a[:,:,np.newaxis]*b[:,np.newaxis,:], axis=0)
```

**Continuing** with the second example, exapnding the example to divide each outer product by a different number can be done as follows:

Assuming the vector pd consists of to numbers (since there fore two outer products), the change needed can now simply be done using::

```
pd = np.array([[[6]],[[8]]])  # shape is (2,1,1) because there are two outer products
solution = np.sum((a[:,:,np.newaxis] * b[:,np.newaxis,:]) / pd, axis=0)
```

Another method will be to set `pd` as a (1,2) shaped array, and divide a prior to multiplication:

```
pd = np.array([[6,8]])  # shape (1,2) beacuse there are two outer products
solution = np.sum((a / pd)[:,:,np.newaxis]* b[:,np.newaxis,:], axis=0)
```

*Regaurding the Einstein summation* proposed in the other solution, you can go with:

```
pd = np.array([[6,8]])  # shape (1,2) beacuse there are two outer products
solution = np.einsum( 'ij,ik->jk',a/pd,b)
```

Comment: I have updated the question with the exact code. And I need to divide each of the outer products by a number. How would I do that? –

Comment: I added the change to the answer :)